# Laravel form echo variable

Tags: php, forms, laravel, variables, echo

i am still learning how to work with laravel.
Now i have learned how to make a form in laravel. But i have some trouble to echo a variable.
What i want to do is: i want to echo a variable as the value of an input-field if this variable exists, otherwise it should echo nothing.
so my form line looks like this

```
  {{Form::text(
    'league_name',
    '@if(isset($varialble) {{$variable}} @else {{$nothing}} @endif)'
  )}}
```

How can i echo a variable in a form?

i am using blade btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way to do it:

```
{!! Form::text('league_name', isset($varialble) ? $variable : '') !!}
```

If you're using PHP7, you can do this:

```
{!! Form::text('league_name', $varialble) ?? '') !!}
```

**Update**

To add placeholder, pass it in an array as third parameter. Also, you usually want to pass a class:

```
{!! Form::text('league_name', isset($varialble) ? $variable : '', ['placeholder' => 'My placeholder', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: thx thats working. But how is it possible to echo a placeholder if $variable doenst exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Here You can use **null** instead of $nothing and $variable is your variable

```
{{Form::text('league_name',$varialble ? $variable : $nothing)')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel use can use normal PHP code also

> {!! Form::text('league_name', !empty($varialble) ? $variable : '') !!}

here you can use **{!! data/variables !!}** or **{{ data/variables }}**

above will resolve your problem.